# Create a list from a string extracted from another list with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, collections, sharedpreferences

In my application, I use this class as a model:

```
class ExpenseItem (val concept: String, val amount: String, val months: List<String>, val type: Type, val cards_image: Int, val payDay: Int, val notes: String) {

    enum class Type {RECURRENT, VARIABLE}
}
```

And with this model, I create a mutable list

```
var generalExpensesList: MutableList<ExpenseItem> = mutableListOf()
```

and I add items

```
 val currentExpense = ExpenseItem(
                    concept,
                    amount,
                    listOfMonths,
                    enumtype,
                    card_image_number,
                    payday.toInt(),
                    notes
                )

                generalExpensesList.add(currentExpense)
```

*As you can see, one of the model fields is also a String type list, in case it was important*

Well, my intention is to convert this list to String, save it as a sharedpreference, and then create a new list using that String retrieved from the sharedpreference.
To convert the list to String I can use toString or joinToString, both give me an optimal result.
I have the problem when I want to create a new list from the String.
I can do it with lists of type `List<String>`, but never with lists of type `List<ExpenseItem>`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Using Gson map it to Json and save to SharePreference, and you can easy to retrieved List<ExpenseItem>

Comment: You mean the GSON library, right? I have never used it. I will have to investigate to see how it works. Would you know of any implementation example applied to this?. Thanks

Comment: For instance you have in you sharedPrefs `[one, two]`. Do you want to convert this content form String to List<String>?

Comment: no, the sharedprefs is a string with the data of the model class "ExpenseItem" and that String is what I want to convert to a list of type List<ExpenseItem>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way, you can use `Gson` library, add it to build.gradle, it will serialize your list to `JSON` and save it to `SharePreference`

```
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

```
    public void saveItems(List<ExpenseItem> items) {
        if (items != null && !items.isEmpty()) {
            String json = new Gson().toJson(items);
            mSharedPreferences.edit().putString("items", json).apply();
        }
    }

    public List<ExpenseItem> getItems() {
        String json = mSharedPreferences.getString("items", "");
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(json)) return Collections.emptyList();
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<ExpenseItem>>() {
        }.getType();
        List<ExpenseItem> result = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Gson()** class.
First Make class like below

```
class WhateverName(var generalExpensesList: MutableList<ExpenseItem> = mutableListOf())
```

and pass your list to this class and make a object of this class and then need to make string of it like below

```
Gson().toJson(WhateverName(arrayListOf()))
```

it will give you the string and save it to preference as a string.
After retrieve string from preference you need convert it to that object again for doing that use below code.

```
Gson().fromJson("string", WhateverName::class.java)
```

it will give you the class of **WhateverName**, you can access your list from it.